# Merging 2 arrays and encoding them to Json returns invalid characters

Tags: php, arrays, json

I merge 2 arrays so I can encode it to a Json, but this is what happens:

```
{"\u0000*\u0000_id":1,"\u0000*\u0000_mapper":{},"\u0000*\u0000_avatar":"","\u0000*\u0000_name":"Name","\u0000*\u0000_surname":"Name","\u0000*\u0000_email":"something@domain.com","\u0000*\u0000_gsm":"301313","\u0000*\u0000_password":"somepassword201","\u0000*\u0000_language":1,"\u0000*\u0000_phone":"","\u0000*\u0000_company":"","\u0000*\u0000_vat":"","\u0000*\u0000_registrationDate":"2015-07-07 09:55:31","\u0000*\u0000_address":8,"\u0000*\u0000_lastLogin":"2015-07-24 09:06:45","\u0000*\u0000_username":"someusername","\u0000*\u0000_salt":"12qidjoasidj8192u319ehj129dusafioj","\u0000*\u0000_hash":"","\u0000*\u0000_activated":true,"\u0000*\u0000_timeZone":0,"error":"false"}`
```

These "\", "/" and "u0000" appear when I encode them using `json_encode()`
Code:

```
$user = $this->cache->user;
$response = array_merge((array)$user, array('error' => 'false'));
$this->view->jsonResponse = json_encode($response);
$this->renderScript('/appapi/showjson.phtml');
```

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Please post the output of `var_dump($user)`.

Comment: That's how Unicode strings are encoded in JSON. So apparently `$user` has Unicode property names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by doing this:

```
public function getuserAction() {
    if ($this->checkLoggedIn()) {
        $user = $this->cache->user;
        $info = array('error' => 'false');
        $response = $this->mergeJsons(Zend_Json::encode($info), Zend_Json::encode($user);
        $this->view->jsonResponse = $response;
        $this->renderScript('/appapi/showjson.phtml');
    }
}
//The 'true' parameter means it's gonna create an array from the Json
private function mergeJsons($json1, $json2) {
    $result = array_merge(Zend_Json::decode($json1, true), Zend_Json::decode($json2, true));

    return Zend_Json::encode($result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with merging. Apparently your `$user` object contains **protected properties**, which are [converted to `\0*\0<name>`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.casting) when being cast to an array. Those two `NUL` bytes encode to `\u0000` in JSON format.